# Como simular um browser?

Tags: html, c++, http

Mais especificamente, vou fazer streaming de música com o [MP3Skull](http://www.mp3skull.com), que não tem API. Até agora, o que eu consegui fazer foi usar um HTML Parser e ir div por div procurando pela id comum de todas as músicas. Porém, o número de resultados é limitado. Em um browser comum, é só clicar em "Show more results" (ou algo do tipo), mas usando apenas as informações que tenho, não consigo fazer nada. Qual é a solução?

Comment: Caso ajude, tenho os seguintes recursos: SFML 2.x, Boost 1.57, TinyXML2, tidy.exe (tidylib), rapidjson e Juce. Disposto a baixar outras bibliotecas.

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa forma seria utilizando um Web Crawler como rotina e montar a lista em uma base de dados para não precisar buscar novamente.

[Crawler - GitHub](https://github.com/sylvinus/node-crawler)

[Crawler - npmjs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/crawler)

Comment: Obrigado, Rodrigo. Ando meio sem tempo; vou dar uma olhadela para ver se resolvo o problema.

Comment: Então... minha tag é C++ por isso. Pensei em usar ferramentas como o jQuery, mas sequer uso JS. Vou tentar usar Python para fazer interface e usar um Crawler.